# Why escape & to avoid XSS

Tags: xss

I was just wondering, does anybody know a usecase where not escaping the `&` to `&amp;` leads to Cross Site Scripting vulnerabilities? I thought about it but couldn't come up with an example.

Thanks in advance
Konne

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

&*#39;+alert(1)+&*#39;

was working on search.twitter.com up to earlier today.

https://twitter.com/#!/kinugawamasato/status/38539726470397952

Comment: What does this do? I really don't get it.

Comment: This would pop an alert box on the clients machine.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on where the injection lands, but a simple example would be

```
<a href="&#x6a;&#x61;&#x76;&#x61;&#x73;&#x63;&#x72;&#x69;&#x70;&#x74;&#x3a;&#x61;&#x6c;&#x65;&#x72;&#x74;&#x28;&#x31;&#x29;">XSS</a>
```

which is an html encoded payload javascript:alert(1) which will fire when the XSS link is clicked. This can also be used in an iframe src, document.location=, window.open(), or other methods that would cause the html encoded payload to be decoded and then executed.

Another example would be landing inside of an onevent which reflects the URL with injection such as

```
<a onclick='http://www.foo.com?injection=&#39;*alert(1)*&#39;'>XSS</a>
```

The html encoded payload will be decoded, break out of the onevent syntax and fire the injected javascript.